# Efficient allocation of options across people

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

(Sorry for issues, this question is NOT a duplicate, the question that was a duplicate was a mis-post and has been deleted)

Let's say I have data on people's choices:

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "pear"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear","banana"]
}}
```

What the data means is that jaime doesn't care about getting an apple or a banana. Now I want to run a fair distribution so that each person gets one fruit that's within their preference set, but it doesn't matter which fruit.

There are other conditions:

- If there are too MANY choices (if there's more fruit than people), then someone will still have an extra choice to pick from (see first example below), whereas everyone else is getting 1 thing.
- If there are too FEW choices (if there's less fruit than people), then someone will not get anything at all.
- For simplicity, assume that it doesn't matter who the lucky someone is, or the someone who ends up empty handed, so let's assume it's always down to the last person on the data list
  Given those conditions, consider the following examples.

---

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "pear"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear","banana","orange"]
}}
outcome = {
  "jaime"=>["apple"], 
  "taylor"=>["pear"], 
  "pat"=>["banana","orange"]
}
```

---

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "pear"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "banana"]
}}
outcome = {
  "jaime"=>["apple"], 
  "taylor"=>["pear"], 
  "pat"=>["banana"]
}
```

---

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "banana"]
}}
outcome = {
  "jaime"=>["apple"], 
  "taylor"=>["banana"], 
  "pat"=>[]
}
```

I started brainstorming some code

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "pear"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear","banana"]
}}
fruit_avail = ["apple","banana","pear"]
result = {"allocation"=>{},"will_not_get_anything"=>[]}

# helper array, contains people that are "done" being allocated

finished = []

fruit_avail.each do |fruit|
  unfinished = data["choices"].reject { |person,options| finished.include? person }
  # helper hash, contains people who have yet to be allocated (opposite of finished)

  first_person_who_has_fruit_choice = unfinished.first { |person,options| v.include? fruit }[0]
  # this is the "someone". since i use .first, this will bias toward the first person with the fruit preference in the choices data getting it. In other words, in the absense of enough fruit, the last person will be empty handed, in the presence of too much fruit, the last person will also have the extra choice

  unfinished.each do |person, options|
    if first_person_who_has_fruit_choice == person
      result["allocation"][person] = [fruit]
      finished << person
    else
      updated_options = result["allocation"][person].present? result["allocation"][person] : options
      # helper variable, gets the latest options for this person (which may have been trimmed due to earlier allocations
      remaining_options =  updated_options - [fruit]
      result["allocation"][person] = remaining_options
      result["will_not_get_anything"] << person if remaining_options.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

But the above doesn't catch a scenario where the data is like this:

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear"]
}}
```

Since the code just works down the list, it'll produce the following outcome:

```
outcome = {
  "jaime"=>["apple"], 
  "taylor"=>[], 
  "pat"=>["pear"]
}
```

Whereas the actual correct outcome should be:

```
outcome = {
  "jaime"=>["banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple"], 
  "pat"=>["pear"]
 }
```

Any thoughts or advice appreciated.

Comment: As a start, I think you might try to add a `sort` after you have your list of people & choices, and sort by the number of choices they've listed ascending. Taylor should have got the apple. If you wanted to get more complex with it, you could mutate their preference list as you go, throwing out fruit preferences for each user as fruit is no longer available (and then re-sorting)

Comment: Please edit to clarify "...then someone will still have an option". As I understand,  given a selection of fruits, you wish to assign to each person one of their preferred fruits, if possible, and if that is not possible, you wish to maximise the number of persons who are assigned a preferred fruit. Is that correct? Could the given selection of fruit include two bananas?

Comment: @CarySwoveland see edited , no it can't be two bananas, because that's the same type of fruit (you can't doubly prefer bananas)

Comment: I was referring to the contents of your array `fruit_avail` (though I don't think it matters in terms of the algorithm used to produce a solution). btw, I believe the Rails tag is inappropriate, as it's a pure-Ruby question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brute-force approach to solving what I believe is an NP-complete problem. It is guaranteed to maximise the number of persons who are assigned a preferred fruit.

**Code**

```
def assign_fruit(preferences, basket)
  prefs = preferences.values
  best = [nil, nil, nil]
  best_count = 0
  basket.permutation(prefs.size) do |perm|
    arr = prefs.zip(perm).map { |pref, p|
      pref.include?(p) ? p : nil }
    sz = arr.compact.size
    if sz > best_count
      best = arr
      break if sz == prefs.size
      best_count = sz
    end
  end
  preferences.transform_values { best.shift }
end
```

**Examples**

```
preferences = {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "pear"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"]
}
```

```
assign_fruit(preferences, ["pear", "banana", "plum"])
  #=> {"jaime"=>"banana", "taylor"=>"pear", "pat"=>nil} 
assign_fruit(preferences, ["pear", "banana", "apple", "plum"])
  #=> {"jaime"=>"banana", "taylor"=>"pear", "pat"=>"apple"}
assign_fruit(preferences, ["pear", "banana", "orange"])
  #=> {"jaime"=>"banana", "taylor"=>"pear", "pat"=>"orange"} 
assign_fruit(preferences, ["orange", "orange", "orange"]) 
  #=> {"jaime"=>nil, "taylor"=>nil, "pat"=>"orange"}
```

This method permits the fruit basket to contain a count exceeding one of each fruit.

**Explanation**

If `prefences` is as given in the examples and

```
basket = ["pear", "banana", "plum", "fig"]
```

then

```
prefs = preferences.values
  #=> [["apple", "banana"], ["apple", "pear"],
  #    ["apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"]] 
enum = basket.permutation(prefs.size)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["pear", "banana", "plum",
  #                  "fig"]:permutation(3)> 
enum.size
  #=> 24
```

We can see the elements `enum` will generate and pass to the block by converting `enum` to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["pear", "banana", "plum"], ["pear", "banana", "fig"],
  #    ["pear", "plum", "banana"], ["pear", "plum", "fig"],
  #    ["pear", "fig", "banana"], ["pear", "fig", "plum"],
  #    ...
  #    ["fig", "plum", "pear"], ["fig", "plum", "banana"]]
```

The first element generated and passed to the block is:

```
perm = enum.next
  #=> ["pear", "banana", "plum"]
```

We then compute:

```
pairs = prefs.zip(perm)
  #=> [[["apple", "banana"], "pear"],
  #    [["apple", "pear"], "banana"],
  #    [["apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"], "plum"]]
```

which is then mapped to:

```
pairs.map { |pref, p| pref.include?(p) ? p : nil }
  #=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

showing that nobody received a preferred fruit.

Consider a second example. When:

```
perm = ["pear", "apple", "banana"]
```

we obtain:

```
pairs = prefs.zip(perm)
  #=> [[["apple", "banana"], "pear"],
  #    [["apple", "pear"], "apple"],
  #    [["apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"], "banana"]] 
pairs.map { |pref, p| pref.include?(p) ? p : nil }
  #=> [nil, "apple", "banana"]
```

showing that two persons should be pleased. For each permutation considered, the number of persons receiving a preferred fruit is compared with the best so far. If the number is greater than the best so far, that assignment becomes the best assignment so far. If everyone receives a preferred fruit we can break out of the loop.

Comment: thank you! this is a very thorough explanation as well, which i really appreciate! also incidentally for the `transform_values` block, i didn't realize you could do that... i thought it would've had to have been `preferences.transform_values { |v| best.shift }`

Answer (score 0):

Let’s do it step by step.

```
choices = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana"],
  "taylor"=>["apple"],
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear"]
}}['choices']
```

Let’s now build the reversed hash of fruits => people:

```
fruits_to_ppl =
  choices.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |(k, vs), acc|
    vs.each { |v| acc[v] << k }
  end.sort_by { |_, v| v.size }.to_h
#⇒ {"banana"=>["jaime"], "pear"=>["pat"], "apple"=>["jaime", "taylor", "pat"]}
```

Also, let’s sort ppl by the size of their preferences list:

```
sorted = choices.sort_by { |_, v| v.size }.map(&:first)
```

OK, we are ready.

```
distribution =
  fruits_to_ppl.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |(f, ppl), acc|
    who = sorted.detect { |s| ppl.detect(&s.method(:==)) && acc[s].empty? }
    acc[who] = f if who
  end
#⇒ {"jaime"=>"banana", "pat"=>"pear", "taylor"=>"apple"}
```

This solution is incomplete and it probably requires an explicit handling of what’s left in the bucket afterwards, but this would be a good starting point to accomplish the task.

Comment: got it, so you're iterating for each fruit, looking at list of people sorted by size preferences (prioritizing people with fewest preferences), and looking to see if you can find the first person that does want the fruit-in-iteration that does not already have a fruit assigned in a final allocation. and if you do find that person, then assign it. 

of course as you've said, this stops once each person is assigned one fruit, so doesn't explicitly call out cases where other people have more options, still super helpful (i'm just using comments to digest for myself)

Comment: by the way, just to confirm `ppl.detect(&s.method(:==))` is the same as `ppl.detect { |p| p == s }` right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a verbose solution not optimised just to show the basic idea.

I hope the code is self explanatory, or I'll add an explanation later.

The **basic idea** is to track how many fruits a person is receiving, sorting each time in order to give precedence to the person who has less.

```
data = {"choices"=> {
  "jaime"=>["apple", "banana", "kiwi"], 
  "taylor"=>["apple", "pear","peach"], 
  "pat"=>["apple", "pear","banana","peach"]
}}
fruit_avail = ["apple","banana","pear","peach","melon"]

# setup
people_fruits_request = data['choices'].transform_values { |v| v & fruit_avail }.sort_by{ |_, v| v.size }.to_h
people_fruits_allocation = people_fruits_request.transform_values { |v| v = [] }
people_fruits_count = people_fruits_request.transform_values { |v| v = 0 }
fruit_avail_requested = fruit_avail & people_fruits_request.values.flatten.uniq

# calculation
fruit_avail_requested.each do |fruit|
  people_requesting = people_fruits_request.select { |_, fruits| fruits.include? fruit }.keys
  person = (people_fruits_count.sort_by { |k,v| v}.map(&:first) & people_requesting).first
  people_fruits_allocation[person] << fruit
  people_fruits_count[person] += 1
end

people_fruits_allocation
#=> {"jaime"=>["apple"], "taylor"=>["pear", "peach"], "pat"=>["banana"]}

fruits_left_in_the_basket = fruit_avail - fruit_avail_requested
#=> ["melon"]
```

Comment: so for each fruit you're basically comparing who wants it vs. whatever fruit they already have, and biasing who should get it to the person who has the least number of existing fruit options. i like it! however, this has the same flaw that my code ended up having, where since it runs through the list of people in order, if you feed it data like, where `taylor` only wants an `apple`, because the script will allocate the `apple` first to `jaime` (as the first person), then `taylor` actually ends up with nothing `[]`

Comment: btw, i understand you're just demoing something and it's still very helpful yes. the comments are also something that i'm using to track what's going on, this is turning into a very useful learning exercise for me about different solutions, all of which are still vastly more elegant than what i came up with

Comment: @james I made a small change in the setup, sorting `people_fruits_request` by request size, in order to serve early who has less fruits in request. This fix the case you mentioned.